# Change background after a certain number of collisions in pygame

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I am attempting to switch the background **only** if a certain number of collisions (or hits on the balloons) is detected. The collisions are between a gun and 7 balloons blitted on the screen.

**Note: The collision works perfectly fine.**

Currently, 7 balloons show up and each time I hit a balloon it switches backgrounds. What should happen is when you hit 1 balloon out of 7 on the first background, it changes to the second background where you hit 1 balloon again out of the 7 displayed. When you hit a balloon on the second background, it changes back to the first. Then (back on the first background) you hit 2 balloons (out of 7), where it then changes to the second background where you hit 2 balloons again, and so on.
So the number of hits should be like **1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7; (out of 7 total displayed balloons)** where the first number in each pair is the number of hits in the first background and the second is the new background.

This is what changes the background:

```
for balloon_list_index in num_balloon_list:
    balloon_list_index += 1
    bg_bool = not bg_bool
```

And this is the list of the number of hits needed:

```
num_balloon_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]
```

Here is my full code:

```
import pygame as pg
import random as r
import sys

pg.init()

bg = pg.image.load('bg.jpg')  # Background Image #
bg = pg.transform.scale(bg, (688, 387))
new_bg = pg.image.load('new_bg.jpg')
new_bg = pg.transform.scale(new_bg, (688, 387))

radius = 30
diameter = 2 * radius

num_balloons = 7
bullets_colors_ls = []
iterator = -1

num_balloon_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]
balloon_list_index = 0


def create_balloons():
    global balloon_list
    global colors

    for i in range(num_balloons):
        while True:
            candidate = r.randint(0, 500)
            if all(abs(candidate - x) >= diameter for x in balloon_list):
                break
        balloon_list.append(candidate)


def draw_balloons(y):
    for i in range(num_balloons):
        screen.blit(colors[i], (balloon_list[i], y - 50))


def check_collisions(x, y):
    global hit_var
    global hit
    global score
    global scoretext
    global bg_bool
    global num_balloon_list, balloon_list_index

    for i in range(num_balloons):
        gun_rect = gun.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        gun_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(gun)

        balloon_rect = colors[i].get_rect(topleft=(balloon_list[i], y - 100))
        balloon_mask = pg.mask.from_surface(colors[i])

        offset = (balloon_rect.x - gun_rect.x), (balloon_rect.y - gun_rect.y)
        if gun_mask.overlap(balloon_mask, offset):
            hit = True

            for balloon_list_index in num_balloon_list:
                balloon_list_index += 1
                bg_bool = not bg_bool

            hit_var = i
            score += 2
            scoretext = myfont.render("SCORE: " + str(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
            print(f'hit balloon: {i}')
            break


# Vars #
x = 0
y = 250
velocity = 5
score = 0
hit = False
bg_bool = False
testvar1 = True
clock = pg.time.Clock()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((688, 387))  # Size of the screen #
caption = pg.display.set_caption("Remember")  # Title of the window #

balloon_list = []
b1 = pg.image.load('balloons/1.png').convert_alpha()
b1 = pg.transform.scale(b1, (63, 131))
b2 = pg.image.load('balloons/2.png').convert_alpha()
b2 = pg.transform.scale(b2, (63, 131))
b3 = pg.image.load('balloons/3.png').convert_alpha()
b3 = pg.transform.scale(b3, (63, 131))
b4 = pg.image.load('balloons/4.png').convert_alpha()
b4 = pg.transform.scale(b4, (63, 131))
b5 = pg.image.load('balloons/5.png').convert_alpha()
b5 = pg.transform.scale(b5, (63, 131))
b6 = pg.image.load('balloons/6.png').convert_alpha()
b6 = pg.transform.scale(b6, (63, 131))
b7 = pg.image.load('balloons/7.png').convert_alpha()
b7 = pg.transform.scale(b7, (63, 131))
colors = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7]

gun = pg.image.load('game-gun.png').convert_alpha()
gun = pg.transform.scale(gun, (150, 150))

create_balloons()

pg.display.flip()  # Updating #

running = True  # Game loop bool #

while running:  # Game loop #
    clock.tick(60)

    if bg_bool == False:
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    elif bg_bool == True:
        screen.blit(new_bg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(scoretext, (5, 10))

    if hit == True:
        r.shuffle(balloon_list)
        hit = False

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                check_collisions(x, y)

    draw_balloons(y)

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    x += keys[pg.K_RIGHT] - keys[pg.K_LEFT] * velocity
    x -= keys[pg.K_LEFT] - keys[pg.K_RIGHT] * velocity

    screen.blit(gun, (x, y))
    pg.display.update()
```

You can download all of the images here: [Download images on Replit](https://replit.com/@krmogi/repl-pygame-project#new_bg.jpg)

```
balloons/
  1.png
  2.png
  3.png
  4.png
  5.png
  6.png
  7.png
bg.jpg
game-gun.png
new_bg.jpg
```

How can I change the background after a certain number of collisions (hits on the balloons)?

P.S. [I have asked a question that is a similar concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337320/how-to-display-the-correct-amount-of-images-after-each-collision) with a great answer, but I failed to implement it into this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a global variable to track the number of hits.

```py
num_balloons = 7
num_hits = 0  # Add this
```

When hit, update the number of balloons and the number of hits.

Then, compare the number of hits needed, and if the game has not ended:

- restore the number of balloons,
- reset the number of hits,
- increment the balloon list index to get the next number of hits needed, and
- change the background  .

```py
def check_collisions(x, y):
    # ...
    global num_balloons, num_hits  # Add this

    for i in range(num_balloons):
        # ...
        if gun_mask.overlap(balloon_mask, offset):
            hit = True

            # for balloon_list_index in num_balloon_list:               # Remove this
            num_balloons -= 1                                           # Add this
            num_hits += 1                                               # Add this
            num_hits_needed = num_balloon_list[balloon_list_index]      # Add this
            game_end = balloon_list_index == len(num_balloon_list) - 1  # Add this
            if num_hits == num_hits_needed and not game_end:            # Add this
                num_balloons += num_hits  # Restore balloons            # Add this
                num_hits = 0              # and then reset hits         # Add this
                balloon_list_index += 1
                bg_bool = not bg_bool

            # ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. I will award your bounty shortly.